# Why can't I "shutdown anyway" if Ubuntu One is syncing?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, shutdown

I use Ubuntu 12.04.

My files is small but I can't shutdown computer if Ubuntu One is syncing even when I force shutdown. That mean When I clicked on shutdown button on the panel, System asked me: Ubuntu one is syncing, can't shutdown...Lock screen | cancel | shutdown anyway ----> I clicked on "shutdown anyway". Then shutdown screen appeared and It was counting 1,2 dot but stopped right there. Even 1 hour after, nothing is changed.

I don't know why if it is not syncing, I can shutdown computer easily. So, a friend of mine also has the same issue.

Comment: You can check the Ubuntu One daemon status using `u1sdtool -s` in the terminal. Can you post the output of that?

Comment: I believe you can hit Escape at that screen and see what it's trying to stop.  Can you also post the output of that or take a picture with your phone?

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to let you "shutdown anyway". If it doesn't it's a bug and we'd like [a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)!

Comment: Roberto is the Ubuntu One lead at Canonical.... :)